# python exe runs fine manually, but in windows task scheduler it start and then it crashes

Tags: python, exe, windows-task-scheduler, outlook-api

I created an exe with auto-py-to-exe (onefile).
the exe works fine, but when I want to run this automatically in windows task manager the exe does start, but throw out an error on the location of my file.

[data.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63zix.png)

data.json file is in the same folder as my exe file (I do not use a relative path )

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Filu6.png)

So i wanted to solve this by setting in the windows task scheduler 'start in (optional)' and the path of my folder

[Start in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loQgZ.png)
then my problem with the path to data.json is solved, but my script crashes at the outlook api to read the mails.

If I run the program manually everything works fine.

Has anyone had the same experience and found a solution?

Comment: A potential way around this is to alter the program to receive an argument representing the full file path of `data.json` so that you don't need to rely on `os.getcwd` being what you expect to build the path.

Comment: Please provide the arguments in text-form instead of screenshots. The settings you are using in the task scheduler are cut off.

Comment: Most likely this is permissions issue. Only way to confirm that is to look at system event logs to check what error it throws when it crashes. If it is on the lines of file not accessible or cannot open connection etc., it is because the user under which task is running does not have permissions to execute that operations. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/707600/task-scheduler-the-user-account-does-not-have-perm . Try with a user having administrative permissions to see if works, then work towards user with limited permissions for specific tasks.

Comment: Check out https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193630/principle-of-least-privilege-is-it-ever-a-good-idea-to-give-standard-users-ad

Comment: Thank you for your insights.

It can't be the administrator rights. I have already run several scripts/exe through the windows task scheduler
But it is the first exe that works a bit against it. 

Passing arguments had also occurred to me, but wasn't going to try until there are no other options left.

It is strange that it works manually and not via the task scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you entered a location of where your scipt should be ran in Start in optional text box.

Enter Action Properties -> Actions -> Select your action and click Edit -> Fill your Start in (optional) box with the location of where your script should be started.

This solved my problem that the script couldn't find some of libraries so each time it was ran from task scheduler it crashed.
When I started it manually from Explorer then the script was working fine.

After filling in Start in option it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably doesn't help you, but someone might benefit from this. I used relative paths to read an .env file and the problem was that I highlighted "Run with highest privileges". I could run everything manually, unless I launched it as admin. Fixed it just using full paths in my code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34250198)